# manipulating values using TCHAR*

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing the following code

```
void MaskSensitiveData(TCHAR* szData,bool bEncryptAll)
{
    szData = L"Test";
}
    
void CMFCTestDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    TCHAR szTest[100] = L"This is a Password:myPass";
    MaskSensitiveData(szTest,false);
    AfxMessageBox(szTest);
}
```

I am expecting that the `MaskSensitiveData` method alters the `szTest` and the value is passed
back to the caller. I see the value  is not getting changed. Can you please tell me what I can do to edit the value inside the calling function?

Comment: You will have to copy the string in a similar way as you do a c-string. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-wcscpy-mbscpy?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-wcscpy-mbscpy?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Ths code should not compile as `*szData` is a `TCHAR` and you can't assign a string to a single char,

Comment: I would expect `szData = L"Test";` to compile but not do what you want as `szData` is passed by value. With that said passing by reference will not be what you want either.

Comment: You need something like: `wcscpy(szData, L"Test");` (or one of the other relevant functions in the family).

Comment: Also `MaskSensitiveData` implies some sort of encryption or zeroing.  Don't use any of the standard c-string that expect a `0` terminated string as embedded `0`s upset them.  Use the c-string functions that take a length or preferability use `std::vector<uint8_t>` as the encrypted data type.

Comment: @RichardCritten Would be possible to COBS-encode the encrypted string, too – then it would become compatible to classic C strings again... Advantage: Would allow encrypting in place – or maybe better storing all data right from the start in a `std::vector<TCHAR>` or possibly `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` – while `makeSensitiveData` then would accept a reference to.

Comment: @Aconcagua COBS-encode should work,  I just like a non-string (including std::string) data type for encrypted data as I think it makes it clearer what the contents are and how they should be processed.  I just prefer to use std::vector (as apposed to std::string) for data-buffer like types.

Comment: Note that declaring a variable as TCHAR but then directly assigning a wide character string pretty much defeats the purpose of TCHAR. At this point there is very little point to using TCHAR in new code, you should prefer using wide characters explicitly. That is, declare your variables as wchar_t const * or for windows code LPWSTR or LPCWSTR.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir that's right, `TCHAR` is a solution to a problem nobody's had for 20 years now.  But sometimes old habits die hard, and certainly you're going to see it in a ton of Microsoft documentation.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I take it back, there's still a place for `TCHAR` in code that must be dual compiled for UTF-16 in Windows and UTF-8 in Linux.  But you must pair it with the `TEXT` or `_T` macros on your literals to get the prepended `L` when you need it.

Comment: @MarkRansom There isn't. `TCHAR` is a translation utility for Windows' ABI types, `WCHAR` or `CHAR`. If you need your code to compile for Windows and Linux (i.e. library code) there's no reason to use Windows' ABI types. You'd rather define or alias a type for library use, that maps to the underlying OS' ABI types.

Comment: @IInspectable the reason it was invented has no bearing on why you might find it useful today.

Comment: @MarkRansom I wasn't commenting on the reasons `TCHAR` was invented for. I was commenting on its purpose. And there is no purpose in using a Windows ABI conversion utility when targeting Linux. If you're writing a library that needs to operate on strings with different encodings, have your library provide a library-specific type.

Comment: Manipulating the temporary variable doesn't influence the origin. @logeeks Any update?

Answer (score 1):

In `MaskSensitiveData()`, the `szData` parameter is being passed *by value*, so a *copy* of the pointer is being made, and any new value assigned to `szData` itself inside of `MaskSensitiveData()` will be assigned to that copy and not be reflected back to the caller's original variable.

Also, this code shouldn't even compile, as a string literal is an array of `const` characters (`ie, L"Test"` is a `const wchar_t[5]`), which decays into a *pointer-to-const*, but `szData` is a *pointer-to-non-const* instead, which is not allowed to point at `const` data.

You need to instead copy the *contents* of the string literal into the memory that `szData` is pointing at, eg:

```
void MaskSensitiveData(TCHAR* szData, int iDataLen, bool bEncryptAll)
{
   _tcscpy_s(szData, iDataLen, TEXT("Test"));
}
    
void CMFCTestDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    TCHAR szTest[100] = TEXT("This is a Password:myPass");
    MaskSensitiveData(szTest, 100, false);
    AfxMessageBox(szTest);
}
```

Comment: @logeeks Also have a look at [Parameter passing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170#parameter-passing). Pointer type arguments are passed as integer type arguments.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT unless they are passed by reference/pointer, that is...